# when I physically update my firestore database fields, my app is not able to access those new fields, and displays the old fields

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, field, backend

here is my database
[I have a users collection with documents as each user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAoke.png)

the issue is that, whenever I change a field by using the actual database editing tool, my app is not able to access data

when I query these fields I get the data that was there before I edited it

```
        if let document = document {
            if let username = document.get("user_username") as? String,
            let action = document.get("status") as? String,
            let description = document.get("status_desc") as? String,
            let companion = document.get("user_username") as? String  {
                
                ViewController.myName = username
                self.helloLabel.text = username + "  "
                self.actionArray.append(action)
                self.actionArray.append(description)
                self.actionArray.append(companion)
                
            } else {
                print("missing fields in the status")
            }
            
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist in cache")
        }
    }
```

when I print the status field now, I get the string that was there before, which was not "sleeping"

I am also confused because when I update the fields through the app itself, the database would look exactly the same, but the app is capable of detecting the change and shows the new field

can some one explain why this is happening, or how I would fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Set a listener to receive data-change events in order to listen to realtime changes of a documents with the onSnapshot() method instead of get().

The listener will receive an initial snapshot of the data and another snapshot every time the content changes.

link:

[GET realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)